# Length of shortest line?

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux command using `wc -L` it's possible to get the length of longest line of a text file.

How do I find the length of the *shortest* line of a text file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/135753/109661

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{print length}' <your_file> | sort -n | head -n1
```

This command gets lengths of all files, sorts them (correctly, as numbers) and, fianlly, prints the smallest number to console.

Answer (score 13):

Pure awk solution:

```
awk '(NR==1||length<shortest){shortest=length} END {print shortest}' file
```

Comment: This seems slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

I turned the awk command into a function (for bash):

`function shortest() { awk '(NR==1||length<shortest){shortest=length} END {print shortest}' $1 ;}  ## report the length of the shortest line in a file`

Added this to my .bashrc (and then "source .bashrc" )

and then ran it:  shortest "yourFileNameHere"

```
[~]$ shortest .history
2
```

It can be assigned to a variable (Note the backtics are required):

```
[~]$ var1=`shortest .history`
[~]$ echo $var1
2
```

For csh:

`alias shortest "awk '(NR==1||length<shortest){shortest=length} END {print shortest}' \!:1 "`

Answer (score 1):

Both `awk` solutions from above do not handle '\r' the way `wc -L` does.
For a single line input file they should not produce values greater than maximal line length reported by `wc -L`.

This is a new `sed` based solution (I was not able to shorten while keeping correct):

```
echo $((`sed 'y/\r/\n/' file|sed 's/./#/g'|sort|head -1|wc --bytes`-1))
```

Here are some samples, showing '\r' claim and demonstrating `sed` solution:

```
$ echo -ne "\rABC\r\n" > file
$ wc -L file
3 file
$ awk '{print length}' file|sort -n|head -n1
5
$ awk '(NR==1||length<shortest){shortest=length} END {print shortest}' file
5
$ echo $((`sed 'y/\r/\n/' file|sed 's/./#/g'|sort|head -1|wc --bytes`-1))
0
$ 
$ echo -ne "\r\r\n" > file
$ wc -L file
0 file
$ echo $((`sed 'y/\r/\n/' file|sed 's/./#/g'|sort|head -1|wc --bytes`-1))
0
$ 
$ echo -ne "ABC\nD\nEF\n" > file
$ echo $((`sed 'y/\r/\n/' file|sed 's/./#/g'|sort|head -1|wc --bytes`-1))
1
$
```